# money-rails: Use helpers within a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, money-rails

Im integrating a payments gateway, Im using the gem [money-rails](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails) to handle money in my application, from my controller I have an action to make a charge to the credit card of the user, I would like to use the helpers money-rails has but how it is supposed that you only can use helpers from views then I do not know how to properly get the money amount for sending to the payments gateway, for example, if I have the following money object:

```rb
<Money fractional:650 currency:USD>
```

I would like to get the value `6.5`, for then send it to the gateway, there is a helper for that called: `humanized_money` but I can't use it from a controller. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rails 5, `view_context` is no longer available.... You can either call your helper method inline in your controller using `helpers.humanized_money` or simply call:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.humanized_money
```

Answer (score 2):

Might be a little late, but for accessing helpers from a controller standpoint, you can use

```
view_context.humanized_money
```

This goes for any other view helper.

Comment: No excuse to not go back and use this cleaner and more robust alternative in my opinion. No worries. :)

Answer (score 1):

in your controller where you want to use the money gem do:

`include MoneyRails::ActionViewExtension`

in your method where you want to use the money object, the helpers are now available.

Example:
`money_without_cents(@money)`